# Are bash/shell script questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Once  I posted a close vote to a question relate to bash script in other SE site.But later came to know that bash is on-topic.

Now I got a doubt that on  elementary OS site bash/shell script is on-topic or off-topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what others would say but I think it should be on topic.

On Ask Ubuntu for example, we deal with questions like that all the time, and usually it is the person trying to do automate something on the system or whatever, and counts as "using Ubuntu" (without getting all technical).

Comment: I agree, until it is specifically about something that isn't elementary, it is on-topic.